Remove space before multline/align/gather environment in tcolorbox
When using multline/align/gather environments in a tcolorbox, a spurious space is added within the box and before the equation. Is there a way to remove this space?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    This is a test
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{equation} \label{eu_eqn}
e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0
\end{equation}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{multline*}
p(x) = 3x^6 + 14x^5y + 590x^4y^2 + 19x^3y^3\\ 
- 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3
\end{multline*}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{align*} 
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{gather*} 
2x - 5y =  8 \\ 
3x^2 + 9y =  3a + c
\end{gather*}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}



I don't know about that other question. The answer seems much more complicated than samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's accepted answer below. Indeed, the question itself seem much more complicated

You can either use the ams gather* etc. options so that tcolorbox will automatically make your box such an environment or you could use ams nodisplayskip upper to remove the displayskip:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    This is a test
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams equation]
%\begin{equation} 
\label{eu_eqn}
e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0
%\end{equation}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams nodisplayskip upper]
\begin{multline*}
p(x) = 3x^6 + 14x^5y + 590x^4y^2 + 19x^3y^3\\ 
- 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3
\end{multline*}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align*]
%\begin{align*} 
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
%\end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams gather*]
%\begin{gather*} 
2x - 5y =  8 \\ 
3x^2 + 9y =  3a + c
%\end{gather*}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}



Thanks. It seems ams multline* isn't valid so I'll have to revert to the ams nodisplayskip method for that
